# How to build .ipa and install it on iphone form xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ionic-framework, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have installed MacOS 10.12 Using VMware and successfully implemented Ionic 2 app for IOS. I have also generated an .ipa file using the following method:

1. Clean your project.
2. Build your project.
3. Go to products menu -> select build for -> select Profiling.
4. In project navigator, find your .app product.
5. Right click on it and click show in finder.
6. There you will find folder named "Release-iphoneos", in
   this folder you will find your .app extension file.
7. Create a
   folder named "Payload", copy that .app file in this folder.
8. Archive your folder.
9. After archive, rename your folder to name of
   your app and change its extension from ".zip" to ".ipa"
10. Your ipa is ready for sharing.

From the above technique I got my .ipa file. Then, to install this app on iPhone i am using www.diawi.com . Now the problem is, when i am installing app from my safari browser on iphone download issue is showing. My internet connection is all good. I can also see the installation process on my iphone but app is not installing.

Note: I don't have Apple developer program. I need to build and install this app for testing in different iPhones.

Please suggest any other way to install my app on iPhone or another technique to build and share the app. My configuration is as follows:

Mac OS - 10.12 Sierra(VM-ware machine), Xcode- 8.3.3.

I tried so many articles but not sure where am i getting wrong. please suggest.

Comment: There is no way that you can install your ipa file in devices without a proper provisional profile. To get a provisional file you need to have an Apple Developer Account.
The behaviour that you are seeing might be that the download proceeds till 75% and then it fails. Usually this behavior is seen when your apps provisional profile doesnt have the device id in it.

You can directly run your app in your device by connecting it to your Mac machine and run it. But this wont help you since you want to distribute your app to multiple devices.

I hope this helps

Comment: you needs to valid provisional profile for creating ipa for development . for that you must enroll with apple developer account .

Comment: Or you know someone who can invite you as a developer into his enrolled program and give you access to his certificates.

Comment: @JobinsJohn as per your suggestion, how should i insert device id in apps provisional profile? please suggest

Comment: @paragKartpay I hope you know how to take UDID of the device. 

Once you have the UDID you can add this to the provisional profile created in your apple developer account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you will need to be enrolled with the Apple developer program (99$ a year). There is no other way.

Or you need to install it manually by plugging the iPhone in the computer and running the code in XCode (keep in mind that the default certificate will let your app run for 7 days then it will get expired)

Comment: means i can only run this till 7 days without apple developer program? to test the app i will need to enroll this program? right sir? @Mohammad Bashir Sidani

Comment: No to test the app, you can plug your device, select your device to run  the app on in xcode, and it will be installed and run Normally for 7 days on the device. However to run it on devices for indefinite days and over the air you will need to enroll in the developer program

Comment: If this answers your question please mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

to make .ipa file Archive your project and export your binary as developent or deployment.
You can install your .ipa file manually.Connect your iPhone with your computer and drag .ipa file in your iPhone application folder.